Studying algebraicness of a set determined by polynomials

Let $f, g \in \Bbb{C}[t]$ and $X := \{ (f(t), g(t)) : t \in \Bbb{C} \} \subseteq \Bbb{C}^2$ . Then, $X$ is algebraic on $\Bbb{C}^2$ .

I am trying to understand a proof of this that works as follows.
Let $d = \deg f \geq \deg g = e$ . Take $\hat{f}, \hat{g}$ the homogenization of $f$ and $g$ respectively and define $\varphi : \Bbb{C} \Bbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \Bbb{C} \Bbb{P}^2, [t_0 : t_1] \mapsto [t_0^d : \hat{f}(t_0,t_1) : t_0^{d-e} \hat{g}(t_0,t_1)]$ . At this point, the proof says that there is a polynomial $F \in \Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ homogeneous such that ${\rm Im} \,
 (\varphi) = \mathcal{Z} (F)$, then takes $G$ the de-homogenization of $F$ and shows that $\mathcal{Z}(G) = X$ which is easy to see.
My problem is, why ${\rm Im} \,
 (\varphi) = \mathcal{Z} (F)$? I do not see it, is this map closed on the Zariski topology or something like that? I think that it should be by some propperty of $\Bbb{C}$ since the proof next shows that this result is not true when $f, g \in \Bbb{R}[t]$
EDIT
There is a theoretical result on my book (Curvas algebraicas by Jose F. Fernando Galván) that says the following.

Given an algebraically closed field $K$ and $\varphi_0, \varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in K[t_0,t_1]$ homogeneus polynomials of same degree which do not have irreductible factors in common, there is an homogeneus polynomial $F$ such that $\mathcal{Z} (F) = {\rm Im} \, \varphi$ where $\varphi: K \Bbb{P}^1 \rightarrow K \Bbb{P}^2, [t_0 : t_1 ] \mapsto [\varphi_0 (t_0, t_1), \varphi_1 (t_0, t_1), \varphi_2 (t_0, t_1)]$

I think that this is what it is being applied here, but the only problem is that in the hypothesis does not say anything about $f, g$ being coprimes, so, is there someway to adapt this result to polynomials who have  factors in common?

You mention your book once or twice, but you don't say what that book is. Could you provide that detail in an [edit], please?

@KReiser Of course. I have done it just know

Note. This problem is addressed in MSE:152568. I wish to give an abstract solution.
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Denote affine $n$-space $k^n$ with Zariski topology by $\mathbb{A}^n$. Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials with coefficients in $k$, i.e. $f, g \in k[T]$. Define $\varphi: \mathbb{A}^{1} \to \mathbb{A}^2$ by $$x \longmapsto \left(f(x), g(x) \right).$$ Then we have following map of coordinate rings $\varphi^{*} : k[X, Y] \to k[T]$ such that $$X \mapsto f \quad \text{and} \quad Y \mapsto g.$$ Put $A = k[X, Y] \, / \, {\rm ker} (\varphi^{*})$. Define dimension of $R$ by transcendental degree of fraction field ${\rm Frac}(R)$ over $k$ where $R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and an integral domain. Then dimension of $A \le 1$ since $A$ is a subring of $k[T]$. If either $f$ or $g$ are non-constant, the dimension of $A$ is $1$. Hence applying following theorem from Hartshorne I.1.13 :

Proposition. A variety (irreducible algebraic set) $Y$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ has dimension $n-1$ iff $Y = \mathcal{Z}(F)$ for some non-constant $F \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Remark. If both $f$ and $g$ are constant, then image is a point.
Hope I have not goofed up.

Thanks for your answer! Since I have not studied abstract algebra of varieties, I have some questions since your notation mentions many things that there are not in previous courses. What is $\Bbb{A}$ ? $\dim A$ = 1 because you are understanding $K[t]$ as a $K$-vectorial space of dimension 1 and then using the First Isomorphy Theorem, right? What do you mean by $K= \overline{K}$ ? By variety in the proposition what do you mean? Any possible vectorial subspace of $\Bbb{A}^n$ ?

I tried to edit the post to accommodate your questions.

Thanks for your edit! My problem know is that I do not see how this applies in my case since the proof takes projective spaces, I do not see the relation

The $F$ in the answer is same as the $G$ in the question.

Okay, but why is the the ${\rm Im} , \varphi$ of the proof a variety? This is what I do not see. Is it beacuse the $\varphi$ given between $\Bbb{C} \Bbb{P}^1$ and $\Bbb{C} \Bbb{P}^2$ is projective? And it is, why? The polynomials do not cancel the linearity on the product since they are homogeneus but they should do it on the sum.
